# How do I find the solution for $\frac{x+1}{x-1} \gt \frac 1{x}$?

Tags: inequality

I'm very confused on inequalities. I just came from inequalities with absolute values and tried to solve the above inequality like I did with absolute values. When I compared with my students they seemed to have a different and much more simpler Answer.

\begin{align*}
\text{Given equation:} \quad & \frac{x+1}{x-1} > \frac{1}{x} \\
\text{Case 1:} \quad & x - 1 \geq 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x \geq 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad [1,\infty[ \\
    & \text{Case 1.1:} \quad x > 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad ]0,\infty[ \\
        & \quad \frac{x+1}{x-1} > \frac{1}{x} \\
        & \quad \Rightarrow \quad x^2 + x > x - 1 \\
        & \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x^2 > -1 \\
    & \text{Case 1.2:} \quad x < 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad ]-\infty,0[ \\
        & \quad \frac{x+1}{x-1} > \frac{1}{x} \\
        & \quad \Rightarrow \quad x^2 < -1 \\
\text{Case 2:} \quad & x - 1 < 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad x < 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad ]-\infty,1[ \\
    & \quad \frac{x+1}{x-1} > \frac{1}{x} \\
    & \quad \Rightarrow \quad x^2 < -1 \\
\end{align*}

When I wanted to do the second case I noticed it's same for all equations, so I noticed that the Intervalls are in contradictory, So my Solution is $]0,1[$. Also $R\{1,0\}$.

What would have been an easier way?

Comment: Why would you consider the subcases $x>0$ and $x<0$ when you already in the case where $x\ge 1$? In the case where $x\ge 1$ then automatically $x>0$, and of course $x<0$ can't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the general idea of trying to break down the problem into a bunch of cases, and examine each one of those cases independently.  However, there is no guarantee that the cases you have chosen are useful or correct.  Typically, the approach that you are working through depends on rewriting the original inequality so that it is expressed in the form

$$ \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} > 0, $$

where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials.  The inequality then holds true whenever $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have the same sign.  In this case,

$$ \frac{x+1}{x-1} > \frac{1}{x}
\iff 0 < \frac{x+1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x}
= \frac{x(x+1) - (x-1)}{x(x-1)}
= \frac{x^2 + 1}{x(x-1)} = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}.$$

It is, I think, reasonably clear that $p(x) = x^2 + 1 > 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, which means that the inequality is satisfied if and only if $q(x) = x(x-1) > 0$.  This, in turn, requires that $x$ and $x-1$ have the same sign:

1. if $x < 0$ and $x-1 < 0$, then $x < 0$ (as this is the more restrictive condition—hence $x \in (-\infty,0)$), and
2. if $x > 0$ and $x-1 > 0$, then $x > 1$ (as this is the more restrictive condition—hence $x\in (1,\infty)$).

Since either case gives solutions, the full set of solutions is

$$ x \in (-\infty,0) \cup (1,\infty). $$

---

Personally, I would rather think of this graphically / geometrically.  This is a naive approach—I am not going to use any fancy tools or tricks, and I am not attempting to do anything at all clever.  I am also not dealing with cases, because I am dyscalculiac, and the plusses and minuses are going to mess me up (I promise).

First, the simplification done above:

$$ \frac{x+1}{x-1} > \frac{1}{x}
\iff 0 < \frac{x^2 + 1}{x(x-1)} = r(x) $$

The rational function in the last inequality can be graphed by hand without *too* much difficulty:

- If $x$ is very, very large (either positive or negative), then $r(x)$ is very close to $1$—if you know calculus, this means that $\lim_{x\to\pm \infty} = 1$; if you don't know calculus, you should probably have been taught some other techniques for detecting horizontal asymptotes.
- The numerator has no zeros, which implies that $r$ has no zeros.
- The denominator has two zeros: $x=0$ and $x=1$.  Both of these are zeros of degree $1$, which implies that $r$ has two poles of order $1$.  At each of these poles, the graph possesses a vertical asymptote, and the function crosses the horizontal axis at those points.

These data imply that the graph looks something like

[image]

We are interested in $r(x) > 0$, which means that we are interested in the places where the graph is strictly above the $x$-axis.  From the picture, this corresponds to the set of solutions

$$ x \in (-\infty, 0) \cup (1,\infty). $$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x+1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x} > 0 $$
Or
$$\frac{x^2 +x - x + 1}{x(x-1)} > 0 $$
Or
$$\frac { x²+1}{x(x-1)} > 0 $$

Now $x^2+1>0$ is true for all real values of x. So if $x²+1>0$ and $\frac { x²+1}{x-1} > 0 $ then $x(x-1)>0$ has to be true.

Solving this by wavy curve method, you get $x<0$ or $1<x $

**What is wavy curve method**:-

Wavy curve method is a manner of checking signs of the function whose value we are comparing. If you draw a number line and plot the roots on it, here 0 and 1, you'll see that the function is +ve to the left of 1, -ve between 0 and 1, and +ve again to the right of 0. This symbols alternate from left to right after every root if the root can be expressed as $(x−k)^n$ where n is odd. It doesn't change if n is even

Comment: What is "wavy curve method"?

Comment: I thought it was called “method of intervals” rather than “wavy curve method”.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Well wavy curve method is a manner of checking signs of the function whose value we are comparing.  If you draw a number line and plot the roots on it, here 0 and 1, you'll see that the function is +ve to the left of 1, -ve between 0 and 1, and +ve again to the right of 0. This symbols alternate from left to right after every root if the root can be expressed as $(x-k)^n$ where n is odd. It doesn't change if n is even

Comment: I have never in my life heard that term.  I would suggest that you spell it out a bit in your answer.

Comment: @Aig Maybe. In my books and school it's taught with this name. But the main idea is same I guess

Comment: @XanderHenderson It's a real thing. https://brilliant.org/wiki/wavy-curve-method/. You can even search it up on youtube

Comment: @Gwen I don't care if it is a "real thing" or that it is on Brilliant or YouTube.  As a person holding a PhD in mathematics, who has taught this material more times than I care to count, I have never heard the term before.  This suggests that there are *others* who have not heard the term before, which suggests that if you don't explain what it is, you are leaving your answer incomplete.  Telling readers to visit another website kind of goes against the spirit of *this* site, as questions and answers here should be as self-contained as humanly possible.

Comment: @XanderHenderson oh yeah of course why not. Can I type what I had explained you in the replies in my actual answer, or does it require some more clarification? I'll try my best

Comment: @XanderHenderson I feel this may be a regional difference. In India, in any math competitive examination, it is common to refer to this as the wavy curve method. But indeed an explanation was due.

Answer (score 1):

This might be easier. $$\frac{x+1}{x-1}>\frac 1 x$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{x+1}{x-1}-\frac 1 x>0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac{x^2+1}{x(x-1)}>0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x(x-1)>0,$$ hence the solution set is $$(-\infty,0)\cup (1,\infty).$$

Answer (score 1):

To escape the subcase problem, I will provide a general method here $$\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}>\dfrac{ex+f}{gx+h}$$
The idea is to multiply the **square** of both denominator, so that they must be positive. Hence, it get
$$(ax+b)(cx+d)(gx+h)^2>(ex+f)(gx+h)(cx+d)^2\tag{*}$$
It seems to be quite tough, but actually they have some common factors, so we can factorize them

$$(*)\iff (cx+d)(gx+h)((ax+b)(gx+h)-(ex+f)(cx+d))>0$$
Now $(ax+b)(gx+h)-(ex+f)(cx+d)$ is a quadratic polynomial, solving quadratic inequality is simple, hence the solution can be easily determined.

For example in this case, we have $$(x+1)(x-1)x^2>x(x-1)^2\iff x(x-1)(x^2+x-x+1)>0\iff x(x-1)(x^2+1)>0$$
This time $x^2+1$ is always positive, so it reduces to $x(x-1)>0$, which give the solution $(-\infty,0)\cup(1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Yes it may be somehow too layman, I try to adjust my wordings a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If we add and subtract $2$ at the top of the first fraction, we get $$1+\frac2{x-1}>\frac1x$$We know that when $x>1$, the LHS is bigger than the RHS because $\frac1{x-1}>\frac1x$. If $x<1$ then let $u=-x$ and so $$1-\frac2{u+1}>-\frac1u$$add $\frac2{u+1}-1$ $$0>\frac2{u+1}-\frac1u-1=\frac{-u^2-1}{u(u+1)}$$Which reduces to gwen's case.

Comment: Not necessarily a good answer but just another way to solve the problem.

Comment: I would be careful about making judgement calls about "better" vs "worse".  "Different" is a perfectly acceptable adjective.

Answer (score 0):

i have 2 points to say:

**1. This another way to think:**

We know that $a>b$ so $a+c>b+c$, for all $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}.$

Therefore, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $\frac{x+1}{x-1} > \frac{1}{x}$ then:

$$\frac{x+1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x} > 0$$

where $\frac{x+1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{x(x+1)-(x-1)}{x(x-1)}$. So this is equivalent to:

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x(x-1)} > 0$$

Being $x^2 \geq 0$ for all $x$, we have $x^2+1 \geq 1 > 0$ for all $x$.

Hence to satisfy the inequality, we must have $x(x-1)>0$:

- Taking $x>0$, and $x-1>0$ (or $x>1$), therefore $x>1>0$
- Taking $x<0$, and $x-1<0$ (or $x<1$), therefore $x<0<1$

Then, for all $x > 1$ or $x < 0$, we have $\frac{x+1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x} > 0$

Now, note that. If $x$ satisfy $\frac{x+1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x} > 0$, then $x$ satisfy $\frac{x+1}{x-1} > \frac{1}{x}$.

I don't know if it's clear, this is my first participation here.

**2. In your solution, the case (1) $x-1\geq0$, is equivalent to $x\geq1>0$, so the subcases $x>0$ and $x<0$ is reduntant. That's why it led to contradiction, because if $x>0$ so assume $x<0$ is contradiction.**

(Obs): When $a>b$ and $c<0$ so $ac<bc$. I notice in case(1.2) you inverse the signal, but if $x<0$, so $x-1<0$, then $x(x-1)>0$, multiply $x(x-1)$ not invert the signal in that case.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If we know our strategy is to go from $\frac {x+1}{x-1} < \frac 1x$ to multiply both sides by $x$ and both sides by $x-1$ to get $(x+1)x=x^2 +x ??? x-1$ and then subtract $x$ from both sides to get $x^2 ??? -1$, then we know the key points we have to consider is when $x-1$ and $x$ change signs and how often the $<$ gets flipped to $>$ and how often it gets switched back.

If $x<0$ and $x-1$ less than $0$ (i.e. whenever $x<0$) multiplying by $x$ and multiplying by $x-1$ flips the $<$ to $>$ and back to $<$.

If $x>0$ and $x -1$ are both equal or more than $o$ (i.e. whenever $x\ge 1$) then multiplying by $x$ and by $x-1$ will leave the $<$ sign alone.

And if one is negative and the other positive (which only happens if $0 \le x < 1$) then multiplying by $x-1$ will flip the $<$ to $>$ but multiplying by $x$ leaves it alone.

So if $x <0$ or $x \ge 1$ we have to solve $x^2 < -1$.  And if $0\le x < 1$ we have to solve for $x^2 < 1$.

.... and you have to consider cases when these terms are not define.  That is we can not have $x = 0$ or $x-1 = 0$.

....

Food for thought.  We can simplify $\frac {x+1}{x-1} = \frac {x-1+ 2}{x-1}= 1 +\frac 2{x-1}$.  And I had a lot of fun (your definition of fun may vary) with considering $\frac 1x = \frac {x-(x-1)}x = 1-\frac {x-1}x$ and solving but... as it turned out there is no way I can claim what I ended up with was "easier".  (It was fun though.)

[Essentially we end up with solve $\frac 2{x-1} +\frac {x-1}x < 0$ and so we can't have $x,x-1$ both be positive so we must have $x-1$ is being negative so we must show $\frac 2{1-x}+\frac {1-x}x > 0$ which is the case if $x$ is positive. If $x<0$ if we let $y=-x$ we must have $\frac 2{1+y} < \frac {1+y}y$ or $2y < (1+y)^2 = 1 + 2y + y^2$ or $0 < 1+y^2$ which is impossible.  So $0<x<1$ is the solution.  Like I said....!FUN!]

Also maybe we can replace $y=x-1$ and solve $\frac {y+2}y < \frac 1{y-1}$ but... I don't know if it will make any different.  It *could* and it's worth considering but in this case it probably won't.